# Can a group have $\aleph_1$ many subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

I know that any *countable* group has either countably many or continuum many subgroups ([source](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209537/countable-group-with-uncountable-number-of-subgroups-2-aleph-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but I'm curious about uncountable groups.

It seems like the proof for countable groups $G$ crucially uses the fact that $2^G$ is a polish space, which I think isn't true anymore when $G$ is uncountable. So then:

> Is it possible for an uncountable group to have exactly $\aleph_1$-many subgroups? (Assuming $\lnot \mathsf{CH}$, of course)

More generally, for uncountable cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$, is it possible to have a group of size $\kappa$ with exactly $\lambda$ many subgroups? There are definitely some easy combinations of $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ that we can rule out, but this problem seems like it is probably hard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

As a partial answer, let me prove that any uncountable *abelian* group $A$ always has $2^{|A|}$ subgroups.  Let $T$ be the torsion subgroup of $A$.  Then $|A|=|T|\times|A/T|$ so at least one of $T$ and $A/T$ must have the same cardinality as $A$.  Thus we may assume either $A$ is torsion or $A$ is torsion-free.

If $A$ is torsion, then $A$ is an extension of a direct sum of cyclic groups $B$ by a divisible group $C$.  At least one of $B$ and $C$ has the same cardinality as $A$, and each of them is a direct sum of countable groups.  So at least one of $B$ and $C$ is a direct sum of $|A|$ nontrivial groups and by taking arbitrary subsets of the summands we can get $2^{|A|}$ different subgroups.

If $A$ is torsion-free, then we can pick a basis for the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $A\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ which consists of elements of $A$.  This gives a subgroup of $A$ which is a free abelian group on $|A|$ generators, and again by taking arbitrary subsets of the generators we can get $2^{|A|}$ different subgroups.

Unfortunately, the nonabelian case seems much harder.

---

On the other hand, let me point out that it is possible to have a finitary algebraic structure with exactly $\aleph_1$ substructures (so any proof that this is impossible for groups will have to use something more special about groups).  For instance, consider $\omega_1$ equipped with the following binary operation $f$.  For each infinite $\alpha<\omega_1$, fix a bijection $f_\alpha:\omega\to\alpha$.  Now define $f$ as follows:

- If $n$ is finite, then $f(0,n)=n+1$.
- If $n$ is finite and $\alpha$ is infinite, then $f(n,\alpha)=f_\alpha(n)$.
- In all other cases, $f(\alpha,\beta)=0$.

The first and third bullet points imply that any nonempty substructure $X\subseteq\omega_1$ must contain all finite ordinals.  Then the second implies that if $\alpha\in X$ then $\alpha\subseteq X$, so any substructure must itself be an ordinal.  Conversely, any infinite ordinal $\alpha\leq\omega_1$ is easily seen to be a substructure.  So, the nonempty substructures of $\omega_1$ are exactly the infinite ordinals $\leq\omega_1$, and in particular there are exactly $\aleph_1$ of them.

Comment: Your edit is essentially what I was stumbling towards.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, at least assuming the continuum hypothesis. In the following paper, Shelah proves that there is a group of size $\aleph_1$ whose proper subgroups are all countable.

> *Shelah, Saharon*, On a problem of Kurosh, Jonsson groups, and applications, Word problems II, Stud. Logic Found. Math. Vol. 95, 373-394 (1980). [ZBL0438.20025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0438.20025).

Since every proper subgroup is countable, there are at most $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ subgroups. It is not hard to show there are at least $\aleph_1$ subgroups, so under CH there are exactly $\aleph_1$ subgroups.

Comment: Note to the OP that one aspect of this answer is that the question (even for size-$\aleph_1$ groups) is **not** in fact trivialized by CH: while CH tells us that any group of size $\aleph_1$ has at most continuum many *countable* subgroups, we could have up to $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$-many *size-$\aleph_1$* subgroups.

Comment: That's a good point, @NoahSchweber! I hadn't noticed this subtlety, thanks. I'm still interested in the $\lnot \mathsf{CH}$ case, but I didn't realize the $\mathsf{CH}$ case was also interesting.

Comment: @EdwardH: It is *definitely* interesting. I somehow suspect that a diagonalisation argument can prove otherwise, though.

Comment: Looks like CH got removed! https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.11155.pdf

Comment: @Noah: The CH part in the answer was not about the existence of the group, but the number of subgroups. The preprint you linked, while interesting, relevant, and impressive, is removing CH from a different part of the work.